# What do you call a self-liberated slave?

Tags: slavery

In my story, Tsidia is a slave who managed to inspire people into making slavery illegal, thus setting her free. Is there a word I can use to describe her status in a way that highlights she was the one who liberated herself without the use of violence? I was thinking of self-abolished, but it doesn't sound right

Comment: This is more of a question for writing-SE.  Such terminology rarely falls in Worldbuilding.  That being said, I'd note that such an event occurs rarely enough that there probably is not a term for it, and it will be up to you to come up with a term which meets your needs.  That's something that's more up Writing.SE's alley because it relates what what you need to make your story better.

Comment: @CortAmmon or English.SR.

Comment: In Rome, the term was "libertus", or "liberta" for women. I don't think English has an equivalent.

Comment: Stolen property comes to mind immediately. I think in the American context "runaway" or "runaway slave" were used. Due to the legalities and social constructs involved, I don't think there really was a term for "self liberated". On account of that status not being recognized. I think in America you were either a "slave" a "runaway slave" or a "freedman" on account of purchasing your own freedom or being freed through legal process. Eventually, slaves arriving at the North were considered free --- but only in the North, not the South.

Comment: @ckersch The English equivalent is indeed "Freedman".  But it seems to me that in this case there is no historical precedent to rely on. (as she herself caused the change in laws.)

Comment: *Self-emancipated*

VERB [WITH OBJECT] 1Set free, especially from legal, social, or political restrictions.

‘the citizen must be emancipated from the obsessive secrecy of government’ More example sentencesSynonyms 1.1Law Set (a child) free from the authority of its father or parents. Example sentences 1.2 *Free from slavery*. ‘it is estimated that he emancipated 8,000 slaves’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/emancipate

Comment: @CortAmmon This would most likely be closed as "what to write" on [writing.se]. Word request questions can be asked on [english.se] or [ell.se].

Comment: This is so extraordinary an achievement (as far as I know it has never happened) that no such word exists, so you're going to have to make it up as you go along. I'm inclined to go along with @chaslyfromUK and push for "self-emancipated", but this will always sound a bit odd. And for that matter, she did not emancipate herself (she had no legal authority to release herself from slavery), but rather she convinced the society around her to release her, and that's a bit different.

Comment: A unique term: autolibertas